# Why can we say that there exists a rational $r$ such that $f(x) < r < c - g(x)$ for some real $c$ and $x \in E$ where $E$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

When proving that a linear combination of measurable functions is measurable, the proofs I have seen depend upon the following argument:

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$. For $x \in E$, if $f(x) + g(x) < c$, then $f(x) < c - g(x)$ and so, by the density of the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there is a tional number $q$ for which $$ f(x) < q < c- g(x). $$

Why must this be true?

Comment: Because $f(x) < c - (x)$ means that $(f(x), c-g(x))$ is a nonempty open interval. $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense means every nonempty open interval contains rational numbers.

Comment: That's a great way of looking at it. Thank you!